# Has someone made Adobe native extension for integrating with NextPeer's social plugin

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, air-native-extension

I've searched all over for an ANE which is integrating NextPeer's social plugin, but with no results. I was wondering if someone has ever made it and if it's made where I can find it. Here is the plugin for xCode http://developers.nextpeer.com.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late but you can check out this github project

https://github.com/danielshir/nextpeerANE